# Pause document.ready setInterval with external function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a timer inside document.ready. Like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    timer = window.setInterval(myAction, 3000);

});
```

Then I have a function called pauseTimer() like this:

```
function pauseTimer() {

   timer.pause();           

}
```

But.. why this is not working?

Comment: Because `timer` is a number: [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)

Comment: you are looking for clearInterval( timer);

Comment: @Andreas can i make my own setinterval function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   var timer = window.setInterval(myAction, 1000);
   function pauseTimer() {
    clearInterval(timer )          
   }
   function playTimer() {
    timer = window.setInterval(myAction, 1000);         
   }
   function myAction(){
   console.info('myAction')
   }
   $("#play").click(function(){
     playTimer()
   });
   $("#pause").click(function(){
     pauseTimer()
   });
});
```

HTML

```
<div>
  <button id="play" >play</button>
  <button id="pause"  >pause</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not pause an interval. You can only stop/clear the interval and restart it again if needed.

```js
var timer;

function myAction() {
  console.log('my action');
};

$( function() {
  
  $(document).on('click', '#start', function(){
    timer = window.setInterval( myAction, 3000 );
  });
  
  $(document).on('click', '#stop', function(){
    window.clearInterval( timer );
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="start">Start/Restart interval</button>
<button id="stop">Stop interval</button>
```